# dart/redis: RedisRuntimeError(got element that cant not be parsed)

Tags: dart, redis

I am using redis library in dart. Every time I get error:

> Error retrieving data from Redis: RedisRuntimeError(got element that cant not be parsed)

when I run my function:

```
  static void connect() {
    final url = _IP;
    RedisConnection conn = new RedisConnection();
    conn.connect('localhost', 3022).then((Command command) {
      command.get("TEST").then((var response) {
        var xx = response;
        print(response);
      }).catchError((error) {
        print("Error retrieving data from Redis: $error");
      });
    }).catchError((error) {
      print("Error connecting to Redis: $error");
    });
  }
```

redis is just set up as normal. I changed the ip at redis server .conf-File to 0.0.0.0 - the port was the default one in .conf file (6379) - but I am currently running redis in Oracle VM, so i need to put in the port from the tunnel which is 3022.
In ssh in command tool in windows (VM is running Ubuntu) I can access server normally - also server is running - this is start up info:

````
1225:C 24 Jul 2023 12:38:46.303 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
1225:C 24 Jul 2023 12:38:46.306 # Redis version=7.0.4, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1225, just started
1225:C 24 Jul 2023 12:38:46.307 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
1225:M 24 Jul 2023 12:38:46.307 * Increased maximum number of open files to 10032 (it was originally set to 1024).
1225:M 24 Jul 2023 12:38:46.308 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
                _._
           _.-``__ ''-._
      _.-``    `.  `_.  ''-._           Redis 7.0.4 (00000000/0) 64 bit
  .-`` .-```.  ```\/    _.,_ ''-._
 (    '      ,       .-`  | `,    )     Running in standalone mode
 |`-._`-...-` __...-.``-._|'` _.-'|     Port: 6379
 |    `-._   `._    /     _.-'    |     PID: 1225
  `-._    `-._  `-./  _.-'    _.-'
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |           https://redis.io
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'
      `-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'
          `-._        _.-'
              `-.__.-'

1225:M 24 Jul 2023 12:38:46.312 # Server initialized
1225:M 24 Jul 2023 12:38:46.313 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
1225:M 24 Jul 2023 12:38:46.314 * Ready to accept connections
1225:M 24 Jul 2023 14:35:18.278 * 1 changes in 3600 seconds. Saving...
1225:M 24 Jul 2023 14:35:18.302 * Background saving started by pid 1392
1392:C 24 Jul 2023 14:35:18.321 * DB saved on disk
1392:C 24 Jul 2023 14:35:18.324 * Fork CoW for RDB: current 0 MB, peak 0 MB, average 0 MB
1225:M 24 Jul 2023 14:35:18.404 * Background saving terminated with success
````

When I am checking in command prompt with `GET TEST` I get the value which is `"999"`

does anyone know, what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

okay, problem fixed:
In Oracle VM the port tunnel was not configured - i had to set a tunnel from 6379 to 6379 and changed in code also to 6379